# Is it possible to delete column with special specification(all rows equal) automatically Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have an **trigeer** that updates **Table1** and **one of column named 'Eligible'** after updates can have **all values 'not enough'!**

**Can i delete this column where all values are the same -  'not enough' without checking all rows by myself**?
If it is possible, please explain how?

Code principle would be delete column 'eligible' if all rows the same! I guess?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to check if all the values in the column *Eligible* are the same value *'not enough'*, one way to do this would be to use count in SQL.

Firstly see how many entries there is in total:

```
SELECT COUNT(Eligible) FROM Table1
```

Then check how many entries of *'not enough'* there is:

```
SELECT COUNT(Eligible) FROM Table1 WHERE Eligible = 'not enough'
```

If these two values are the same, then execute:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN column_name
```

In php (Haven't used PHP in a while, so sorry for mistakes):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Eligible) FROM Table1")
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Eligible) FROM Table1 WHERE Eligible = 'not enough'")
if($result == $count)
{
     mysql_query("ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN column_name")'
}
```

Comment: Maybe i was not specific enough. Is it possible to delete not values but all column from table when values in column named 'eligible' **all** rows are = 'not enough'? If there is one value that differs from 'not enough' than that do anything to table!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, do you want to delete all columns from your table? If you delete all columns from your table, there will be no data left in your table, are you sure you don't want to delete rows?

Comment: I want to delete one column if all values in that column are the same!

Comment: Changed my response, I think I understand the issue now.

Comment: Ok i could work with that, but is there are a way to create a function, procedure, trigger that automatically deletes this specific column if all values are the same?

Comment: Thanks C.E.N for answer , but can someone say is it possible to do automatically?

Comment: It is possible to do automatically, but the method varies. Writing a python script that runs every X min should do the trick. But it depends on your setup, and how you want to do it. I suggest re-writing this question.